# Windows 10 sounds are played only when changing speakers volume

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-latitude, realtek-hd-audio

I have Windows 10 Dell Latitude 5420 laptop with the Realtek sound device. Sounds from laptop speaker suddenly stop working. The only sound are played   when volume is changed. Other sounds when trying to run some video or mp3 files are not working. Tried to restart computer, run sound  troubleshoot and reinstall sound driver, but without success.

Running c:\Windows\Media\Windows Background.wav also doesn't play sound, which is strange because the same sound is played when changing volume from volume control.

Does anyone know, what could be the reason for that problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling driver from device manager was not sufficient, hovewer  I have downloaded Realtek HD 3.51 driver file and installed it from exe file and it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to disable: "Enable Audio Enhancements"
https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Dell-5420-i7-i5-Ice-Lake-Audio-amp-USB-Hub-issues/m-p/8301582